# Cannot deserialize data using apache avro

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro

I have a spring boot application that sends and receives data from a kafka broker, i'm using apache avro as a SerDer.
What I've done so far is generate the class using maven plugin, the schema is fairly simple:

```
{"namespace": "com.domain",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
    {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
  ]
}
```

However, I'm getting a very weird exception:

> org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException:
>   Cannot convert from [com.domain.User] to [com.domain.User] for
>   GenericMessage [payload={"name": "a", "favorite_number": 4,
>   "favorite_color": "test6"}, headers={kafka_offset=0,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=batchqueue}]

The following are my configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroDeserializer.class);
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "avro");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, User> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new AvroDeserializer<>(User.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer receiver() {
        return new Consumer();
    }
}

public class ProducerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, AvroSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, User> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public Producer sender() {
        return new Producer();
    }

}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**Update:**
I am not using a dependancy that contains the "AvroSerializer" class, I'm using a class copied from [this](https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-apache-avro-serializer-deserializer-example.html) tutorial.

For the producer class:

```
public class Producer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate;

    public void send(User data) {
        LOGGER.info("sending job data='{}'", data.toString());
        kafkaTemplate.send(topicname, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you publishing the kafka messages?

Comment: @hlagos using an autowired `KafkaTemplate`: `kafkaTemplate.send(topicname, data);`

Comment: can you include the code ? interested on how you serialize the data or if you use AvroSerializer

Comment: @hlagos ok I have updated the question, hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks for updating! can you paste the full stack and your AvroDeserializer? it should be enough to found the issues :p

Comment: Well dont know if that would help, I believe it is a classloader problem, I replaced `public void send(User data)` with `public void send(Object data)` when I print the class of `data`, I get `com.domain.User`, however, instanceof always returns false